# How to put variables into formula in vba

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

The script is as follows :

```
Sub Macro1()

Lastrow1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,5).End(xlDown).Row

For y = 2 To Lastrow1

If Cells(y, 6) <> "" Then
    Cells(y, 7).Formula = "=Networkdays(E2,F2,$S$2:$S$14)"

Else
    Exit For
End If

Next y

End Sub
```

My problems start with the formula here ; for example, I would like to pick E2,F2 and those constant "$S$2:$S$14" and then loop to E3,F3 and so until until in "F columns" it finds nothing and the loop will end.

Any hint on this one? Probably this has been asked quite a few times but once you start, the problem is not only the lack of knowledge but as well lack of the skill of asking the correct question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub Macro1()

Lastrow1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlDown).Row

For y = 2 To Lastrow1
    If Cells(y, 6) <> "" Then
        Cells(y, 7).Formula = "=Networkdays(E" & y & ",F" & y & ",$S$2:$S$14)"
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: ok, trying really hard to bite my tongue.  All I'll say is I tried this with `Sheet2` selected and the code didn't run successfully after I'd sorted out the `Variable not defined` error and my `Lastrow1` was always 1048576 because it starts at row 1048576 and looks down from there.  _Rant over_ :)

Comment: In my case it's solved, thank you
I just didn't know to put properly include variable in the formula part

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the below code.
It finds the last row (use `xlUp` rather than `xlDown`) and places the formula between row 2 and the last row in column G.

```
Public Sub InsertFormula()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

        'Put the formula in the range G2:G & LastRow
        .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Formula = "=Networkdays(E2,F2,$S$2:$S$14)"
    End With

End Sub
```